# Is it possible to inverse the select statement in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

When I want to select all columns expect *foo* and *bar*, what I normally do is just explicitly list all the other columns in select statement.

`select a, b, c, d, ... from ...`

But if table has dozen columns, this is tedious process for simple means. What I would like to do instead, is something like the following pseudo statement:

`select * except(foo, bar) from ...`

I would also like to know, if there is a function to filter out rows from the result consisting of *multiple* columns, if multiple rows has same content in *all* corresponding columns. In other words duplicate rows would be filtered out.

```
------------------------
A     | B      | C      
------------------------    ====>    ------------------------
A     | B      | C                   A      | B      | C
------------------------             ------------------------
```

Comment: Q1: No. Q2: `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Answer (score 2):

You can query `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` db and get the list of columns (except two) for that table, e.g.:

```
SELECT REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME), '<foo,bar>,', '') 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = '<your_table>' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = '<database>';
```

Once you get the list of columns, you can use that in your select query.

Answer (score 1):

You can create view based on this table with all columns except these two columns and then use this view everytime with

```
select * from view
```

simple group by on all column will remove such duplicates. there are other options as well - distinct and row_number.

Comment: I understand the restriction to not be able to make inverse selection, as this would break the contract between database and client application. Every query could return totally different result. But it would be handy feature for quick observation of the table. In view creation you have to do even more work for this simple mean, and doesn't fit.

Comment: okay. My assumption was that you are using this particular table without these columns multiple times. This will reduce your efforts by re usability of that sql.

Answer (score 0):

> `select * except(foo, bar) from`

This is a frequently requested feature on SO. However, it has not made it to the SQL Standard and I don't know of any SQL products that support it. I guess when the product managers ask their developers, MVPs, usergroups, etc to measure enthusiasm for this prospective feature, they mostly hear, "`SELECT * FROM` is considered dangerous, we need to protect new users who don't know what they are doing, etc."

You may find it useful to use `NATURAL JOIN` rather than `INNER JOIN` etc which removes what would be duplicated columns from the resulting table expression e.g.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Table1 t1
       INNER JOIN Table2 t2 
          ON t1.foo = t2.foo
             AND t1.bar = t2.bar;
```

will result in two columns named `foo` and two named `bar` (and possibly other repeated names), probably de-duplicated in some way e.g. by suffixing the range variable names `t1` and `t2` that `INNER JOIN` forced you into using.

Whereas:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Table1 NATURAL JOIN Table2;
```

doesn't require the use of range variables (a good thing) because there will only be one column named `foo` and one named `bar` in the result.

And to remove duplicated rows as well as columns changed the implied `SELECT ALL *` into the explicit `SELECT DISTINCT *` e.g.

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
  FROM Table1 NATURAL JOIN Table2;
```

Doing this may reduce your need for the `SELECT ALL BUT { these columns }` feature you desire.

Of course, if you do that you will be told, "`NATURAL JOIN` is considered dangerous, we need to protect you from yourself in case you don't know what you are doing, etc." :)